# Firestore FCM token not saving at app launch

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to save a token for Firebase Cloud Messaging (var is fcmToken in code below). The issue I am having is the token doesn't initially save to the document when first launching app.

It saves when I either restart the simulator or exit out of the app completely - then opening the app back up. Any help would be much

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {    
      func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: 
            String?) {
               //grab token
          } 
        }

     extension AppDelegate :    
          UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
              func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                             willPresent notification: UNNotification,    
                                 withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping 
                                    (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
                                    if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
       print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
```

}

```
  `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` {
   
       Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
       Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .prod)
       }
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
      didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
 }
     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                             didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                             withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {    
   let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
       if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
               print("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")    }
              completionHandler()   } 
          }

     class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
       let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
       launchOptions:    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
       FirebaseApp.configure()
   
       Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
   
       if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
           // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
   
           let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
               options: authOptions,
               completionHandler: { _, _ in })
       } else {
           let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
               UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
           application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
       }
   
       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
   
       // Save the FCM token when the app launches
       if let deviceToken = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
           saveFCMToken(deviceToken)
       }
   
       return true    }
       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   
       if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
           print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
       }
   
       print(userInfo)
   
       completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)    }
       private func saveFCMToken(_ deviceToken: String) {
       guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
   
       FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument    { document, error in
           if let error = error {
               print("Error checking for device token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
               return
           }
   
           // If the document exists, the device token is already saved
           if let data = document?.data(), let existingToken = data["token"] as? String {
               print("Device token already saved")
               return
           }
   
           // If the document doesn't exist, save the device token to Firestore
           FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).setData(["token":    deviceToken], merge: true) { error in
               if let error = error {
                   print("Error saving device token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                   return
               }
   
               print("Device token saved")
           }
       }    
    } 
  }
```

Comment: I was able to make it work by saving the token as a UserDefault, then passing it to my parent view to save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call save `token` in `didReceiveRegistrationToken` like this.

**Scene 1:** As you mentioned here while re installing app or on restart app this method will call and receive token. so, don't need record it every time. until it change it will be same.

**Scene 2:** if token will change than it will genrate new token and call that method again.

Check given note inside function.

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    if let token = fcmToken {
        //Send FCM Token To Server
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
        self.saveFCMToken(token)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't fix the issue